# MonteCarlo simulation - Create 100 data.frames with rows grouped randomly with a fixed number of subsequent days

Tags: r, date, random, grouping, montecarlo

Here an example of my data.frame and let's assume that the `date` col represents days:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID date
a 1
a 2
a 3
a 4
a 7
a 12', header = TRUE)
```

So, my days here range from 1 to 12 and I would like to create 100 data.frames where for each one the `date` (and `ID`) col will be grouped randomly by 3 subsequent days.

e.g.

df1

```
ID date group
    a 1 1   #group 1 = 1, 2, 3
    a 2 1
    a 3 1
    a 4 2   # group 2 = 4, 5, 6
    a 7 3   # group 3 = 7, 8, 9
    a 12 4  # group 4 = 10, 11, 12
```

df2

```
ID date group
    a 1 4
    a 2 1  #group 1 = 2, 3, 4
    a 3 1
    a 4 1
    a 7 2  #group 2 = 5, 6, 7  ---  group 3 = 8, 9, 10
    a 12 4 # group 4 = 11, 12 and start again from the beginning 1
```

df3

```
ID date group
    a 1 1
    a 2 1
    a 3 2  #group 2 = 3, 4, 5
    a 4 2
    a 7 3  #group 3 = 6, 7, 8 -- group 4 = 9, 10, 11
    a 12 1   #group 1 = 12, 1, 2
```

etc...

Note that the `group` col groups the rows by 3 by considering subsequent days which not necessarily appear in the data.frame and the randomness of the whole trick is the start day of group 1.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure but you can create an empty list and fill new data frames similar to your example:

```
set=list()
for(i in 1:100) { set[[i]] = cbind(df,group=sample(rep(c(1,2),each=3))) }
```

Comment: Hi and thank you. the thing is that my groups need to be subsequent chunks of 3 subsequent dates

Comment: I m trying to understand your example, is the subsequent sample of dates dependent on the date column? Or does it depend on the grouping variable, cq if there are four unique 'groups' then you have 12 subsequent dates.

Comment: thanks, yes! the subsequent sample of dates depends on the date column. eg df1: group 1 = dates 1, 2, 3; etc... I just need to group my data.frame by 3 subsequent dates 100 times based on the random start of group 1

Comment: So its not only date based but also group-based as the follow up date is dependent on the group occuring in sequence (if group 2 is followed by 4 skip the group 3 sequence). Also, I m confused why sometimes 11 is followed by 12 and sometimes by 1,2 (for group 1). In the df3 example, the values for group 4 (however not in the list) overlap with group1 right?

Comment: I updated my question. group 4 has got only 2 observations because the data is not divisible by 3. when group 1 does not start from row 1 the group values at the end of the data.frame will be recycled starting again from the beginning.

Comment: hi, I made my question even simpler by considering dates divisible by 3. thanks

Comment: oef having a hard time solving the chunking problem using loops, my bad, I ll try some more options! Hope someone has an elegant tidyr-based solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43718535/create-10-000-date-data-frames-with-fake-years-based-on-365-days-window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143093/discussion-between-timfaber-and-aaaaa).